# Mesh convergence and its affect on results

Tags: mechanical-engineering, ansys, meshing

Let’s say I had a mesh with 10000 nodes, then made another with 13000 nodes, why would the finer one give me slightly different results to the other even if it appears like results converged?

Also, why do results vary lots before they converge? Why don’t they converge straight away?

Comment: Let’s say that equations have positive and negative roots…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you are trying to approximate real solution using simple shape functions. Depending on the problem, you may need to use lots of elements to be able to describe the solution with sufficient accuracy.

It is a feature of FEA that if your model is correct, the value you are trying to calculate should converge to the exact solution when you are refining the mesh. Just try "mesh convergence". When you right click on a result in the tree, you can add "convergence" to it and ANSYS will try to refine the mesh automatically.

Regarding varying results before convergence in nonlinear analysis, ANSYS uses Newton method and especially in cases where the load step is big, the method may make a lot of wrong guesses all over the place. After a certain number of iterations, where solution has not been found, this is stopped, the load step is halved (bisection) and Newton method starts again.

Comment: Hi sorry I’m still confused, why is it that then the solutions are very random in early iterations?

Comment: Basically Newton method converges very fast if you start near the solution. On the other hand, it may fail to converge if you start far away. To get around this issue, ANSYS uses load step bisection, which basically moves solution at the end of the step half way closer to the start.

Comment: Why is a finer mesh better than a coarser one please?

Comment: Just imagine you are trying to describe a smooth curve using just linear segments. The more segments you have, the more accurate the description will be.

Comment: Hi thank you! That makes more sense